# What is the best case for a function: Database connection in function or pass it as argument?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a page where I establish a database connection at first. I use this for some queries and after that I also use some functions. And now I'm not sure whats the best practice for a function: pass database connection as argument or create a own database connection in the function?

Create database connection in function

```
function get_Number_of_Entries() {
  $mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST,MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASSWORD,MYSQL_DATABASE);
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $count = $stmt->num_rows;
  $stmt->close();
  return $count;
}
```

As argument "$stmt", no database connection created in function

```
function get_Number_of_Entries($mysqli) {
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $count = $stmt->num_rows;
  $stmt->close();
  return $count;
}
```

Comment: 1 Vote for. Pass connection as a parameter. Making connections is a slow process

Comment: I'd suggest passing it as an argument, then you're not creating a *new* connection for each time you call the function. But you need to pass it as `$mysqli`, not `$stmt`.

Comment: @Qirel Thanks for the hint. I have corrected it.

Comment: @all Thanks für your comments, really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, passing the connection as argument will be a better solution.
making connection it's an expensive action, and more than that, more than one connection can be make a real trouble. it can be lock the database and many more scenarios.

I would be recommending to read about Singleton pattern:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

or factory pattern:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Comment: Thanks for your informations and your hints. It helps me to understand the situation.